# Character's Arms and hands Stretching/deforming after exporting animation as FBX file

Tags: animation, rigging, export, inverse-kinematics

I've created a custom rig using the workflow shown in Pierrick Picaut's "The Art of Effective Rigging" course. Everything seemingly works when creating animations inside of blender, but once I export the character and its animation as an FBX file, the arms and hands are stretching/deforming. This occurs both when importing the file to Blender and Unreal Engine and is present in two separate animations (walk cycle & run cycle)

I suspect there may be something wrong with the IK for the arms, but I'm quite new to rigging and animation as a whole, so I can't say for sure.

Does anyone know what could be causing this?

I Uploaded a short video showcasing the animation working as expected in Blender, then not working as expected after being exported as FBX and imported into Blender: https://youtu.be/7XpMT4Kvzts

Comment: Update: Funnily enough, after being stuck on this problem for a very long time, I found the solution less than an hour after finally deciding to ask for help here.

Solution: I noticed that not all of my Deformation bones were connected to the ROOT Bone, so I selected all deformation bones in edit mode, then selected the root bone, pressed CTRL + P and parented the def bones to the root bone with "Keep offset"

Arms no longer deform and stretch. Issue resolved.

Comment: Hi. Please don't add "*Solved*" to your question or title. Instead we encourage you to post an answer below with a short description of the solution and what steps you took to reach it. Perhaps add a few [images](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963) illustrating the workflow and final results. See [How do I write a good answer?](https://blender.stackexchange.com/help/how-to-answer)